# How to use the rollback using multiple database updates in oracle?

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, postgresql

I want to update with multiple databases and each database contains the multiple tables. If a problem occurs I want to rollback all the databases and tables to the original state. Can you give me any one to suggest what can I do for this? Thank you for spending your time to read this question.

Comment: You've tagged this for three different databases.  Are you trying to coordinate updates across three heterogeneous databases (i.e. update an Oracle database, a MySQL database, and a PostgreSQL database in a single transaction)?  What language is your application using?  Are you using a transaction coordinator of some sort?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now am trying with oracle and SQL server only. At the same time i want to know the postgresql.

Comment: Are you trying to coordinate a transaction that affects multiple Oracle databases?  Multiple SQL Server databases?  Or do you want to coordinate a transaction that affects both a SQL Server database and an Oracle database?  Are you using the Oracle definition of "database" or the SQL Server definition.

Comment: Hi justin , first i want to update the multiple oracle databases. give me the solution for it. Once again i thank you for reply.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a program to connect to all the databases at once and initiate a lock on the tables that would be getting updated.

Apply your changes and in the event of an exception, rollback the current database and all previously completed databases.

The aim is to keep one session in sync on all the databases - not a pretty thing to do.

Your other option is to see if you can configure a Zero Downtime install. This is where you break the install up into sections - what can be applied first, what can be applied after.

i.e. you can add a column to all tables (hopefully) without issue so this would be the pre-install. You can not remove a column until it is no longer consumed so this is a post step. This would involve having multiple versions for stuff like views and packages to allow the application to transition without any impact.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update multiple Oracle databases in a single transaction, the simplest option is to create a database link between them.  That causes Oracle to automatically use a distributed transaction.

On database 1, you create the database link

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK to_db2
  CONNECT TO CURRENT_USER
  USING `<<TNS alias to db2>>`;
```

And then a session in database 1 can update tables in both databases as part of the same transaction

```
UPDATE table1
   SET some_column = some_value
  ...

UPDATE table2@to_db2
   SET some_column = some_value
  ...

commit;
```

It is possible to create database links from Oracle to non-Oracle databases using Heterogeneous Services but that is a bit more work particularly if your Oracle databases run on Unix and may require purchasing one of the Transparent Gateway products.

Now, if you are trying to update the same tables in both databases, you shouldn't be writing code for that.  Instead, you should be using one of the various replication technologies to replicate a change on one database to another database.